# sorting a list of females and males

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have an input:

```
4
m.hosSein.python
f.miNa.C
m.aHMad.C++
f.Sara.java
```

and I must sort it in the way that first comes all f(females) ordered by alphabet then comes all m(males) ordered by alphabet. This is the desirable output:

```
f Mina C
f Sara java
m Ahmad C++
m Hossein python
```

.here is my code:

```
`n=int(input())
lst=[]
for i in range (0,n):
x=input().split('.')
lst.append(x)
list=sorted(lst,key=lambda x:(x[0],x[1]))

for item in lst:
if item[0]=='f':
    print(item[0],item[1].capitalize(),item[2])
else:
    print(item[0],item[1].capitalize(),item[2])`
```

my code dose not sort f.(females) correctly and Sara comes first. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in class with that name.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your `for` loops.

Comment: Since `f` comes before `m`, you don't need to split this at all.  Just sort the list as one big unit.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, I tested it but did not work

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  It cannot "not work".

Comment: try not to split `x`, and use `sorted(lst, key= lambda x: x.lower())`. Upper case letters are always smaller then lower case letters

Comment: @TaQ, C++ must be upper. your code modes it lower

Comment: Your code is borken.  Fix the indentation and formatting.  Why does the last `if` exist when both `print` are the same?  Don't use `list` as a variable name.  You *can* edit your question and fix all the problems otherwise you just get comments on the distractions.

Comment: @Ali, it will not change original input and used only for comparison. But just in case `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.lower().rsplit(".",1)[0])` you can eliminate the end part.

Comment: @TaQ, I did but I give this error:" list object has no attribute lower"

Comment: @Ali, then probably you did something wrong. I post below your code with modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should be fine

```
n = int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(0, n):
  x = input() # no split as above comments 
  lst.append(x) 

# remove end part (no need for comparison
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.lower().rsplit(".",1)[0])
print(lst)

# if you really need to split you can do 
for item in lst:
  item = item.split(".")
  # what is the point of this IF stateement ? (OP, please check the logic here )
  if item[0] == 'f':
    print(item[0], item[1].capitalize(), item[2])
  else:
    print(item[0], item[1].capitalize(), item[2])
```

Output :

```
f Mina C
f Sara java
m Ahmad C++
m Hossein python
```

Comment: I want to have the right output , my code dose not work with your beginning.

Comment: I believe the right output means this (edited above)

Comment: I got your advise before looking your complete answer. Thank you and excuse me for bad code. I got your point.